# Prove that if $A=\frac{1}{2}\{B,A\}$ then $B=1\!\mathrm{l}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

So, manipulating some (square) matrices, $A$ and $B$, I encountered an equation of the form:

$$A=\tfrac{1}{2}\{A,B\}$$
where "$\{\cdot,\cdot\}$" denotes the [anticommutator](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Anticommutator.html) between matrices $A$ and $B$: $\{A,B\}\equiv AB+BA$. In order to solve the equation for $B$, I want to show that $B$ must be equal to the identity (matrix):
$$B=1\!\mathrm{l}\equiv \mathrm{diag}(1,1,\ldots,1).$$

Is it always true? I tried to look for a proof for the previous statement but I didn't succeed... 
In fact, I only tried to multiply the equation, on the left and/or on the right, by something like $A^{-1}, B^{-1},(AB)^{-1},\ldots$.

Is my statement right anyway? Does anyone have any suggestion on what to do with this equation?

Thank you all very much in advance!

---

EDIT: as I know that $B=1\!\mathrm{l}$ is not the unique solution to the equation $A=\frac{1}{2}\{B,A\}$, how can I find all the solutions for arbitrary dimensions matrices?

In my answer I provided a condition for the solution with $2$-by-$2$ matrices. There exists a general solution for higher conventionalities matrices?

Comment: $2A=AB+BA$ may be rearranged as $A(2I-B)=BA$.  Hence if $A$ is invertible, then $det(2I-B)=det(B)$.  Note: $A=0$ works for any $B$, so certainly $B=I$ is not necessarily true.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @vadim123! Anyway, now that I have the equation $\det (2I-B)=\det (B)$, how can I solve for $B$? Does actually a solution exist?

Comment: I know that $\det(I+B)$ equals $1+\det(B)$ plus many other traces of $B$ and its powers... Actually, the results is increasingly complicated as the dimension of the matrix $B$ increases!

Comment: Let us suppose that $A$ is invertible and exclude the trivial case where $A=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose the edit I added to my question as a possible answer. If you have any suggestion to improve this answer, please leave me a comment. Thank you all!

Following the hint given by vadim123, we can try to solve the equation by means of the determinants. First of all, we can  rewrite the equation as:

$$2A = AB+BA\\
A(2\,1\!\mathrm{l}-B)=BA.$$
Than, taking the determinant of both sides:
$$\det(A)\det(2\,1\!\mathrm{l}-B)=\det(A)\det(B)$$
which simplifies into
$$\det(2\,1\!\mathrm{l}-B)=\det(B),$$
provided $A$ is invertible. Now, taking a look at the [matrix cookbook](http://orion.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), equations ($25-27$), we can find that, for $n=2$, that is for $A,B$ $2$-by-$2$ matrices, we have:
$$\det(2\,1\!\mathrm{l}-B)\stackrel{(25)}{=}2^2-\det(B)-2\mathrm{Tr}(B)=\det(B),$$

so, for every $2$-by-$2$ matrices, the solutions of the equation $A=\tfrac{1}{2}\{A,B\}$ must satisfy the relation:
$$2-\mathrm{Tr}(B)=\det(B).$$
Of course, $B=1\!\mathrm{l}$ is a solution. Anyway, the general solution is:
$$B={b_{11}\ b_{12}\choose b_{21}\ b_{22}}:\quad 2-b_{11}-b_{22}=b_{11}b_{22}-b_{21}b_{12}.$$
For example,
$$B={0\ -1\choose 2\quad 0}$$
is a solution different from the identity.
The case for higher dimensions matrices is more complicated, but I guess that similar results to the case $n=2$ will hold; hence, there always exist solutions for $A=\frac{1}{2}\{B,A\}$ different from the identity!

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true if you mean $A=\frac12(AB+BA)$ for **all** $A$ (proof: consider, for each $i$, the matrix $A=E_{ii}$ whose only nonzero entry is a $1$ at the $(i,i)$-th position). If you mean $A=\frac12(AB+BA)$ for **some** $A$, the statement is not true except in the $1\times1$ case. For a counterexample, consider $A=B=E_{11}$.

Comment: Hi @user1551! Thank you for your contribution! I got to the same conclusions! Anyway, I can't understand why $A=B=E_{11}$ isn't a solution. Indeed, $E_{11}E_{11}=E_{11}$, hence $E_{11}=\frac{1}{2}(E_{11}+E_{11})$...!

Comment: @AstoundingJB Of course $B=E_{11}$ is a solution, but $E_{11}\ne I$ (unless in the 1x1 case). So, it is a counterexample to the statement that $B$ must be equal to the identity matrix.

Comment: Oops! My apologies, I misunderstood your statement! You're absolutely right, $B=E_{11}$ is a solution when $A=E_{11}$ and it is a counterexample to my previous statement: $B=I$! Thank you again!